# Countdown timer in Swift that keeps running after app shutdown

Tags: ios, swift

I'm developing a social media app and I need to implement a countdown timer that will keep running, even after the app is shutdown completely.  Basically exactly how Snaps in Snapchat behave. Is there a way I can do this within the app, or does this need to be done from the database that will contain app records, users, friends, etc? I'm fairly new to Swift, and I'm using Swift 4, so please keep answers to Swift 3/4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A good question to ask yourself is if a `Timer` is necessary or if you could simply just store a start `Date` and then calculate the current time compared to that stored start `Date` and check if it exceeds your countdown time. If you wanted to demonstrate a countdown timer in a UI similar to a snap in snapchat disappearing perhaps the following simple example would help:

```
let allowableViewTimeInterval = TimeInterval(10) // 10 Seconds
let refreshTimeInterval = TimeInterval(1) // 1 Second refresh time on the label
let snapOpenedDate = Date() // the date they opened the snap

let label = UILabel(frame: .zero) // a label to display the countdown

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: refreshTimeInterval, repeats: true) {
    let currentDate = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateComponents = calendar.components(CalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: snapOpenedDate, toDate: currentDate, options: nil)
    let seconds = dateComponents.second
    label.text = "\(seconds)"
}

// If the countdown finishes or a user leaves the snap we need to make sure we invalidate the timer.
timer.invalidate()
```

You can then adapt this to your solution by storing the snapOpenedDate and looking it up again when an app resumes from background.